# uploading data from excel sheet to sql through phpexcel

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I am uploading an Excel sheet of 3400 rows to MySQL database using php Excel. But it is only able to upload 3000 entries. I have checked all duplicates and everything for the primary key column. Everything is fine.

Just when printing the data through print_r from the Excel sheet it shows complete data 3400 rows but when trying to import to SQL it only imports 3000 entries

Earliest help would be highly appreciated ..

```
include_once("config.php"); 
include_once("function.php");

if (isset($_POST['addproduct'])) {
    //error_reporting(0);
    set_time_limit(0);  ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '100M'); 
    ini_set('memory_limit','128M');

    $con->query("UPDATE products SET STOCK='out of stock'") ; 

    function newsku($item)
    {   
        $olditem = trim($item);
        $olditem = str_split($item);
        $newsku = '' ; 
        foreach ($olditem as $a)
        {
            $newsku .= $a + 1;
        }
        return $newsku ; 
    }

    set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'Classes/');
    include 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

    $inputFileName = $_FILES["uploadsheet"]["tmp_name"];
    $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);

    echo '<hr />';

    $sheetData = $objPHPExcel
        ->getActiveSheet()
        ->toArray(null, true, true, true)
    ;

    foreach ($sheetData as $data) 
    {
        $row = 0;
        $col = 0;       
        if (empty($fields)) 
        {
            $fields = $data;
            continue;
        }
        foreach ($data as $k => $value) 
        {
             $results[$col][$fields[$k]] = $value;
        }
        $col++;

        foreach ($results as $dt)
        {   
            $ITEM = $dt['ITEM'];
            $query = "INSERT INTO `products` set ";
            $result_field = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM products");
            while ($fieldinfo = mysqli_fetch_field($result_field))
            {  
                if ($fieldinfo->name == 'NEWSKU') {
                    $query.=$fieldinfo->name."='".newsku($dt['ITEM'])."'," ;   
                } elseif ($fieldinfo->name == 'STOCK') {
                    $query .= $fieldinfo->name."='in stock'," ;   
                } else {
                    $query .= $fieldinfo->name."='".trim($dt[$fieldinfo->name])."'," ;
                }
            } 
            $query = trim($query, ",");

            mysqli_query($con, $query);

            $con->query("UPDATE products SET STOCK='in stock' WHERE ITEM='".$ITEM."'") ;
        }

    }   
}
```

Comment: Anything on the logs? If you use a file with less than 3000 rows, does it work?